# Fetching Terms Related to Same Taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Lets First Understand The Situation.

I have a Music Website

Songs are Posts
Artists are Category

Now Suppose "Song A" Attached To "Artist A" and "Artist B"

When I visit to the Song, I can see both Artist Listed There using get_Terms.

But When I visit To Artist A Page, I want to Show Artist B as Collaborated Artist.

So In short, Suppose in multiple Songs, Artist A Worked With Different Artist.. So All Artist should come of Artist A Page.

Is it Possible ?

Tried Solution :

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); {
            $post_id = get_the_id();
            $terms = get_the_terms($post_id, 'artist');
            if (!empty($terms)) {
                $artist = array_pop($terms);
                $artist_name = $artist->name;
                $artist_image = get_field('header_image', $artist);
                $artist_id = $artist->term_id;
                $artist_link = get_term_link($artist);
            }
            $songs[$count] = array(
                "post_id" => $post_id,
                "post_url" => get_the_permalink($post_id),
                "id" => $count,
                "name" => get_the_title($post_id),
                "artist" => $artist_name,
                "url" =>  esc_html(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'download_link', true)),
                "views" =>  stripslashes(get_post_meta($post_id, 'post_views_count', true)),
                "cover_art_url" => stripslashes(get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id)),
                "category" => $category,
                "favourites" => get_favorites_button($post_id)
            );
            ++$count;
        }


    endwhile;


    wp_reset_query();
    $json = json_encode($songs);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $collab_artist = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($obj as $song) {
        $collab_artist[$count] = array(
            "artistname" => $song->artist
        );
        ++$count;        
    }
    print_r($collab_artist);
```

Result :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [1] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [2] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [3] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [4] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [5] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [6] => Array ( [artistname] => Urvashi Kiran Sharma ) [7] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [8] => Array ( [artistname] => Kuhu Gracia ) [9] => Array ( [artistname] => Kuhu Gracia ) [10] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) [11] => Array ( [artistname] => Anurag Ranga ) )
```

Now the Problem is, I want to Ignore the Current Artist and its showing one artist only

Comment: This is the website... or say Artist Page 

https://awesong.in/artist/anurag-ranga/

On the Left Side, I want to List All the Artist From the Posts where This Artist is Assigned with other Artist

Comment: I mean what you tried with code?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to show `Collaborated Artist?` be specific.

Comment: On Artist Taxonomy Page, the Link l Shared in the Comment